# How could I Install openmodelica in my docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, openmodelica

I have set up a docker image and install ubuntu on it. Can you please tell me how can I install Openmodelica inside ubuntu to that docker image?

for example, if I want to install node.js on this docker image I could use this code:

```
apt install nodejs
```

so I need some codes like that to install open Modelica on my docker image.
p.s: my docker image is an ubuntu image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happened to create a Docker image for OpenModelica to debug something, so I might add it here as well. We got this questions in the [OpenModelica](https://www.openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/3140-openmodelica-docker-image-available) forum as well.
While the answer of @sjoelund.se will stay up to date this one is a bit more explaining.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Export DISPLAY, so a XServer can display OMEdit
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0

# Install wget, gnupg, lsb-release
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt install -y wget gnupg lsb-release

# Get the OpenModelica stable version
RUN for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt `lsb_release -cs` stable"; done | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
RUN wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | apt-key add -

# Install OpenModelica
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt install -y openmodelica

# Install OpenModelica libraries (like all of them)
RUN for PKG in `apt-cache search "omlib-.*" | cut -d" " -f1`; do apt-get install -y "$PKG"; done

# Add non-root user for security
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash openmodelicausers
USER openmodelicausers
ENV HOME /home/openmodelicausers
ENV USER openmodelicausers
WORKDIR $HOME

# Return omc version
CMD ["omc", "--version"]
```

Let's build and tag it:

```sh
docker build --tag openmodelica:ubuntubionic .
```

### How to use `omc` from the docker image

Let's create a small `helloWorld.mo` Modelica model:

```
model helloWorld
  Real x(start=1.0, fixed=true);
equations
  der(x) = 2.5*x;
end helloWorld;
```

and a MOS script which will simulate it, called `runHelloWorld.mos`

```
loadFile("helloWorld.mo"); getErrorString();
simulate(helloWorld); getErrorString();
```

Now we can make our files accessible to the docker container with the [`-v` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) and run our small example with:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v $(pwd):/home/openmodelicausers \
  openmodelica:ubuntubionic \
  omc runHelloWorld.mos
```

Note that `-v` needs an absolute path. I added `--rm` to clean up.

### Using OMEdit with a GUI

I'm using Windows + Docker with WSL2. So in order to get OMEdit running I need to have a XServer installed on my Windows host system. They are not trivial to set up, but I'm using [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and so far it is working for me. On Linux this is of course much simpler.
I'm using this config to start XLaunch:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XLaunch WindowMode="MultiWindow" ClientMode="NoClient" LocalClient="False" Display="-1" LocalProgram="xcalc" RemoteProgram="xterm" RemotePassword="" PrivateKey="" RemoteHost="" RemoteUser="" XDMCPHost="" XDMCPBroadcast="False" XDMCPIndirect="False" Clipboard="True" ClipboardPrimary="True" ExtraParams="" Wgl="True" DisableAC="True" XDMCPTerminate="False"/>
```

But when the XServer is running you can use OMEdit in nearly the same fashion you would from a Linux OS, just mount some directory with your files and that's it:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v $(pwd):/home/openmodelicausers \
  openmodelica:ubuntubionic \
  OMEdit
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get some inspiration from the Dockerfiles that are used to generate the OpenModelica docker images. For example: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelicaDockerImages/tree/v1.16.2

Comment: thanks, and could you help me with how could I use openmodelica from that? for example, I have some simple examples and want to run these examples from openmodelica on the image.